# Should I be taking more advantage of the server controls in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I started programming in C# and ASP.NET about a year ago. When I was first learning I programmed against all of the toolbox controls, gridview, repeater, etc. But at my current level I rarely touch those controls. I would prefer to use jQuery for validation, LINQ to SQL and a string builder to create my own grids/repeaters and etc. However, I extensively use the label, textbox, and DDL controls, but I feel like I'm working against the framework, or not using it to the potential that it was created for.

Does anyone else have the same habits, or is just me? Should I be using most of the toolbox controls rather than making my own lighter versions in the code behind?

On a side note, i've been reading a book on ASP.NET MVC and think it is where I want to transition to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be highly subjective.  There are some good arguments for both sides.  However, based on the little you said, I think that you would probably be one of the ones that likes MVC.

My own personal view is:

The controls/Web Forms approach is good for rapid development. It's easy to crank out decent functionality with little effort.  This is a very good thing in shops where there is little time/budget, and you want to get solid products out quickly with little effort.  Personally, I prefer Web Forms.  However, Web Forms are not for everyone.  One of the drawbacks is that you lose some fine-tuned control.  Also, the WebForms model is unique.  You won't find a good comparison in most .NET environments.

However, the MVC approach is good for giving you more control, and it's an approach that is used outside of the .NET community.  It's based on some good fundamental principles.

I'm guessing that since you prefer to "use JQuery for validation" this tells me that you prefer "non-forms" tools.  JQuery is one of those things used by more than just the.NET community, and is a general web development tool to use.  MVC, likewise, is something that is "bigger" than just .NET.  That's what makes me think you'd thrive in the MVC environment.

Either way, it's a personal choice, so this is just an opinion.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like a transition to MVC will be perfect for you.

Also, this question should be a wiki

Answer (score 0):

Its a very good sign that instead of using the top level things, you build your own things from scratch. This is not to be considered as "Working against FX", but you are utilizing more than us. Most of the guys in programming world uses the built in controls to avoid LOCs. But most of the Pro uses complex yet effective code. So this is their own way of programming. Everybody has his own way of coding as Coding is Fun for programmers.. it gives you different way of seeing the things. Whatever way you feel comfortable... is the way for you to program.

So dont worry and be happy.... Happy Programming.